# Send user input during call in amazon connect using nodejs

Tags: reactjs, aws-sdk, amazon-connect

Hi I'm working on Amazon connect in nodejs
During the call I need to send some data but I'm unable to find the method.

I know the connect function and onConnect, onAccepted but not able to find the correct method in nodejs or js.

getting the help from this document but here is also nothing - https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md?plain=1#connectionsenddigits

I tried useEffect and useSelector but its not working in ReactJs

Comment: The sendDigits method you mentioned seems to be the correct one. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to update the contact attributes?

If so you can't do this via the streams API. You can only programmatically update attributes via the regular Connect AP. One way to achieve this would be by setting up an API gateway that your custom softphone calls. The API Gateway then calls a Lambda that uses the Connect API to update the contact attributes.

There is a great workshop example of this method [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/pausing-and-resuming-call-recordings-with-a-new-api-in-amazon-connect/). Note that this example is for pausing and resuming calls, but it should be simple enough to use this as a template and replace the calls to `SuspendContactRecording` etc. with calls to `UpdateContactAttributes`